# finding the courses not taking in Staff table ? using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have two tables 
The First one contains information about staff who take courses 
[image: the first table which is named Staff]

The second table information about all courses available and it must taking by staff
[image: second table which named Course]

I want quereu SQL  to find the remaining course for every staff

for example :-

Rami         intro. Java

Rami         into. to Orcad

Rami          PIC

Rami         intro. to C++

Rayan       Intro. Flash

Rayan       Intro to c++

Rayan        PIC

Rayan       Intro. to Photoshop

Rayan       Into. to Orcad

.

.

.

.
.
.
.
.
and so on for all staff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With these 3 tables ...

Courses:

```
CourseName
intro. Flash
intro. Java
intro. to Photoshop
into. To Orcad
intro. to c++
PIC
```

Staff:

```
sname
Khalid
Rami
Rayan
```

StaffCourses:

```
sname   Trainingcourse
Khalid  into. To Orcad
Rami    intro. Flash
Rami    intro. to Photoshop
Rayan   intro. Java
```

... this query ...

```
SELECT
    xjoin.sname,
    xjoin.CourseName
FROM
    [
        SELECT Courses.CourseName, Staff.sname FROM Courses, Staff
    ]. AS xjoin
    LEFT JOIN StaffCourses
    ON
            (xjoin.CourseName = StaffCourses.Trainingcourse)
        AND (xjoin.sname = StaffCourses.sname)
WHERE
    (((StaffCourses.Trainingcourse) Is Null))
ORDER BY
    xjoin.sname,
    xjoin.CourseName;
```

... produces this result set:

```
sname  CourseName
Khalid intro. Flash
Khalid intro. Java
Khalid intro. to c++
Khalid intro. to Photoshop
Khalid PIC
Rami   into. To Orcad
Rami   intro. Java
Rami   intro. to c++
Rami   PIC
Rayan  into. To Orcad
Rayan  intro. Flash
Rayan  intro. to c++
Rayan  intro. to Photoshop
Rayan  PIC
```

Comment: Thanks my friend i rebuild the tables as you make
and every thing is OK :)

Answer (score 2):

Didn't test! But it might work:

```
SELECT staff.Name, courses.CourseName 
FROM courses LEFT JOIN staff
             ON (staff.TrainingCourse = courses.CourseName)
WHERE TrainingCourse IS NULL
```

Comment: I don't think this will work.  If a course has nobody registered for it yet it won't show up in the OP's first table, yet in the query resultset there should be one record for each staff.  You're query won't handle that situation correclty.

Comment: This sql gives the courses not taken by all staff just
not every staff and remaining course 

thanks for answer

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume you have a Staff table with 1 record per staff member, and a courses table with 1 record per course.  And the first table in your post I'll call the CourseRegistrations table.

```
SELECT Staff.Name, Courses.CourseName 
FROM Courses CROSS JOIN Staff
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM CourseRegistrations 
                  WHERE Name = Staff.Name 
                  AND TrainingCourseName = Courses.CourseName)
```

If you're not familiar with CROSS JOIN's what this is doing is finding all possible combinations of staff and courses, then in the WHERE clause it filters out all combination that already exist in your registration table.

Comment: I use ACCESS 2007 

the error said THERE IS ERROR IN FROM ITSFiledTraining CROSS JOIN  ITSStaffTraining  and it shadow the JOIN

Comment: Not sure if access supports cross join.  Try changing the from to: FROM Courses, Staff WHERE NOT EXISTS ...   If you don't specify any join the default should be a cross join (cartesian product)